# Nginx - redirect specific requests on root folder to subdomain

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3

I currently have an hosting website that previously hosted images locally.
Before the current system, image links were referenced from the root folder

EG:

```
https://example.com/image.jpg
```

We have since moved to AWS S3 storage and in order to direct legacy image requests to S3, we added the following to our nginx conf file.

```
location ~* ^/.*\.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ "$scheme://i.example.com/$1" permanent;
}
```

However this captures all image files on the domain.

Is there a way to only redirect requests for image requests on the root domain and ignore other folders?

For example, users avatars are stored locally in

```
https://example.com/content/images/user/qwerty.jpg
```

These get redirected to the subdomain due to the regex.

I also attempted this with the S3 proxy_pass. However results were the same.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

To select only image files in the top level directory, you should replace the `.*` element of your regex with something that does not match `/`. Such as:

```
location ~* ^/[^/]*\.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg)$ {
    return 301 $scheme://i.example.com/$request_uri;
}
```